# Difference between `signal.signal` and asyncio's `EventLoop.add_signal_handler`

Tags: python, signals, python-asyncio

It seems both allows registering handler function to handle signals. What sets `add_signal_handler` apart from `signal.signal`?

Answer (score 0):

I should have read the document more carefully. The [document of `add_signal_handler()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.add_signal_handler) states the difference:

> Unlike signal handlers registered using signal.signal(), a callback registered with this function is allowed to interact with the event loop.